# Как узнать температуру ЦП в Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Библиотеки pyspectator и psutil не работают. psutil работает лишь на linux, а pyspectator просто отказывается работать. Есть еще какие-нибудь библиотеки?

Comment: `psutil` работает и на windows: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#summary (список из Linux Windows
 macOS FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD Sun Solaris AIX). Другое дело, что сенсоры температуры работают только на линуксе: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1280

Comment: У меня выдает пустой принт OpenHardwareMonitor:

Answer (score 3):

[Решение нашел в использовании](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49909330/5909792):

- модуля [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) (`pip install pythonnet`), он позволяет работать с **.NET**
- библиотеки [OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/)

**Для получения полной информации нужно запускать скрипт с правами администратора.**

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/da5847191eaec490b2c8f4a6d4d123c1cf3b9ed1/pythonnet__examples/OpenHardwareMonitorLib__Sensor_Temperature/main.py#L65)

```
import os

# pip install pythonnet
import clr

openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes = [
    'Mainboard', 'SuperIO', 'CPU', 'RAM', 'GpuNvidia', 'GpuAti', 'TBalancer', 'Heatmaster', 'HDD'
]
openhardwaremonitor_sensortypes = [
    'Voltage', 'Clock', 'Temperature', 'Load', 'Fan', 'Flow', 'Control', 'Level',
    'Factor', 'Power', 'Data', 'SmallData'
]

def initialize_openhardwaremonitor():
    DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    dll_file_name = DIR + R'\OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll'
    clr.AddReference(dll_file_name)

    from OpenHardwareMonitor import Hardware
    handle = Hardware.Computer()
    handle.MainboardEnabled = True
    handle.CPUEnabled = True
    handle.RAMEnabled = True
    handle.GPUEnabled = True
    handle.HDDEnabled = True
    handle.Open()
    return handle

def fetch_stats(handle):
    for i in handle.Hardware:
        i.Update()
        for sensor in i.Sensors:
            parse_sensor(sensor)

        for j in i.SubHardware:
            j.Update()
            for subsensor in j.Sensors:
                parse_sensor(subsensor)

def parse_sensor(sensor):
    if sensor.Value is None:
        return

    # If SensorType is Temperature
    if sensor.SensorType == openhardwaremonitor_sensortypes.index('Temperature'):
        type_name = openhardwaremonitor_hwtypes[sensor.Hardware.HardwareType]
        print(f"    {type_name}. {sensor.Hardware.Name!r} "
              f"Temperature Sensor #{sensor.Index} {sensor.Name} - {sensor.Value}°C")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("OpenHardwareMonitor:")
    HardwareHandle = initialize_openhardwaremonitor()
    fetch_stats(HardwareHandle)
```

Для дополнительной информации по работе с API **OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll** обращайтесь к https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/

---

**PS.**

Пока разбирался, нашел некоторые "подводные камни":

- Код вида `clr.AddReference('OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll')` не работает: нужно или убирать `.dll` из строки, или указывать абсолютный путь к `dll`
- Не получится импортировать **CPUThermometerLib.dll**, т.к. пространство имен `CPUThermometer` из библиотеки не существует, даже больше -- у библиотек **OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll** и **CPUThermometerLib.dll** с какой-то версии пространства одинаковые, что намекает на объединение кода или форк (пруф см. в скриншоте ниже).
  Поэтому из того ответа убрал использование **CPUThermometerLib.dll**, оставив **OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll**
- Библиотеку **OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll** можно будет скачать [с офф. сайта](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/) (скачать и вытащить из архива с программой) или [сразу из папки примера](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/da5847191eaec490b2c8f4a6d4d123c1cf3b9ed1/pythonnet__examples/OpenHardwareMonitorLib__Sensor_Temperature)

**CPUThermometerLib.dll** и **OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll** одно и тоже:

[image: Элемент списка]